# Parsing string to DateTime format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have following string `"16:07:57.796"` how i can parse it to this `6/18/2011 16:07:57` ?

If I just try to parse it `DateTime.Parse("16:07:57.796")` I get `6/18/2011 04:07:57 PM`
And it's not what I need.

Thanks for help.

Comment: what do you mean? `6/18/2011 16:07:57` is only a string representing that DateTime. you can get a string with any format from your DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is parsed correctly (as 4 pm is 16) but it is your locale information which displays it differently than you want. You should use the following [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576.aspx) method, which takes an IFormatProvider, in which you can pass in a [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) that fits you.

Otherwise you can format your string using [custom date and time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) formats like the following:

```
date.ToString("M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's parsing the string fine.  You just want to display it in 24-hour format instead of 12-hour format (16:07:57 is the same as 4:07:57 PM).  Try something like `DateTime.Parse("16:07:57.796").ToString("M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss")`.

Answer (score 0):

It's correctly parsing it to the specified time on the current date.

If you don't want the current date, you can use the overload that takes a `DateTimeStyles` parameter, and specify `DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault`. In this case, the date will be 01/01/0001.